# .htaccess rewrite url with parameter

Tags: .htaccess

I want to change my url with only the parameter. As I am passing only one parameter, so I want the sub url should be changed with my parameter name. I want change the url as the following type-

From:

http://www.xyz.com/cat.php?slag=season

to

http://www.xyz.com/season

Can anyone help me to do it. I don't know how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you rather be using http://xyz.com/category/season/ ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /path/to/your/directory 
RewriteRule ^(.*)cat/(.*)$ cat\.php?slag=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

put the above in your .htaccess file.. and that would do the magic..

Note :
`RewriteBase /path/to/your/directory` 
(use this line only if your application is in any of subfolder the folder)

Comment: Won't work unless he uses a domain.tld/cat/foo permalink structure, right?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you obtain a copy of the .htaccess that WordPress uses. It's a quite powerful starting point that allows you to handle routing internally from within your Application - which you might feel more comfortable with, as it seems to me.